# How to setTimeout before the AngularJS ng-click trigger

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, settimeout, angularjs-ng-click

I need a way to set a timeout before the ng-click is triggered, something like:

```
window.setTimeout("ng-click='myCtrl.myFunction()', 1000")
```

I don't think it is possibile but I really need to have this kind of effect. 
I have a very particular animated button, when it is clicked it has to call a function in my controller, but that function has to be invoked only when the buttons animation is finished. (**I can't use** `setTimeout()` or something like that **inside** the function because it keeps the button pressed, and my function has to be executed after the button "get up").

Comment: `window.setTimeout("ng-click=myCtrl.myFunction()", 1000)`

Comment: [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy  nope, already tried, no error but not working.

Comment: @AlonEitan I don't think this is possible, my view don't know what it is $timeout, right?

Comment: @Giulio No it doesn't - You need to put the code inside the `$timeout` callback function in your controller

Comment: Well, you could add the timeout for your function inside the click handler. e.g. function myFunctionHandler() { setTimeout(myFunction, 1000); }

But it would be better to do this in an event based way rather than timeouts. That is, have the click handler register an event handler then when the animation is finished an event will be dispatched to your listener.

Comment: @illvm This is an angularJS question, so recommending to use `setTimeout` is wrong. Angular has its own implementation for this function

Comment: 1. Of course you can use $timeout inside control function. Actually you should. 2. There is no 'pressed' state in html, after user clicks on button it takes focus, thats it. Mouse up and down events also triggers. Actually you more likely has problem with your animation.

Comment: Solved. Thanks to all!!

Comment: Great! You (or the user who solved it) should post the solution as an answer so the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

A user solved the problem but he have deleted his answer, anyway, here is the solution:

```
$scope.clickOnUpload = function () {
  $timeout(function() {
    angular.element('#myselector').triggerHandler('click');
  }, 100);
};
```

Comment: I would like but I can't, when I try it says: "You can accept your own answer in 2 days"

Comment: Ok sorry, didn't know that!